# button to pass value to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php code with this line:

```
<input id="sample" name="btnViewTutorial" type="button" />
```

and when clicked, a javascript would run:

```
var sampleButton = document.getElementById("sample");
sampleButton.onclick = function(){
    window.open ("/tutorials/sample.php", "mywindow","status=0,toolbar=0,height=480,width=600,directories=0");  
}
```

What i would like to do is, when the button is clicked, `/tutorials/sample.php` should have the value passed by the button, like `tutorials/sample.php?video=1` or `tutorials/sample.php?video=ff56gskkd2`.

How would I have the button passed in a value? and How would java script receive the value?

Comment: how about using a form instead?

Comment: What you can do, is just append the value to the URL.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña i want the page to be like a pop up.

Comment: @Kao i wanted it to be dynamically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the querystring to the url. For example, if value of a video is a `data` attribute you can do something like this:

```
<input id="sample" name="btnViewTutorial" type="button" value="View Tutorial" data-video="1"/>
```

And in Javascript:

```
var sampleButton = document.getElementById("sample");

sampleButton.onclick = function(){
    console.log(this.dataset.video);
    window.open ("/tutorials/sample.php?video="+ this.dataset.video,
                 "mywindow","status=0,toolbar=0,height=480,width=600,directories=0");  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A65xg/

Comment: Where did the dataset.video in the Javascript came from?

Comment: From `data-video="1"` attribute, you can read about custom data attributes here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes